# python3 context manager force early exit

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

I need to create a context manager that, when certain conditions are met, can be forced to exit early.

More details:

The context manager needs to handle checking/locking/releasing a resource. On `__enter__`, the context manager needs to check if the resource is locked. If it is, I'd like to have `__exit__` called without executing the code in the context. Otherwise, the context manager acquires the resource, executes the context code, and cleans up the resource in `__exit__`.

It might look something like this:

```
class my_context_manager:
    def __enter__(self):
        if resource_locked():
            self.__exit__(None, ResourceLockedException(), None)
        else:
            acquire_resource()

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        if not isinstance(exc_info[1], ResourceLockedException):
            release_resource()
        else:
            log.warn("Resource already in use.")
```

The code above doesn't actually work, however, because calling `__exit__` inside of `__enter__` doesn't stop the code within the context from being executed.

Alternatively, I could throw `ResourceLockedException` from within `__enter__`, but then `__exit__` won't be called, since the exception would be thrown from the context manager itself. I'd like to be able to catch the exception, log a warning, and not enter the context if the resource is locked.

This comes down to finding some way of closing the context early, so that `__exit__` is called and the context code isn't executed. Is there some way to tweak either of the ideas above to do this? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can't manually call `__exit__` like this. One other alternative is simply `raise` the exception and let another construct manage it. You could either use a `try-except` or whip up another context manager to log these:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def log_exception():
    try:
        yield
    except ResourceLockedException as e:
        log.warn(e)
```

and change your original context manager to:

```
class my_context_manager:
    def __enter__(self):
        if True:
            raise ResourceLockedException("Resource already in use")
        acquire_resource()
    def __exit__(self):
        release_resource()
```

And call it with:

```
with log_exception(), my_context_manager():
    # do things when resource acquired.
```

Of course you could simply use a `try-except` and nest `with` inside that or use an `if` clause alternatively.